# Value Event Listener returning Null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am new in android and Kotlin. I have a user database in Firebase which looks like this:

[image: User Data Format]

I am trying to get the current user data on a realtime basis from firebase using the following code:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val userid = user?.uid
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

if (userid != null) {    
    mRef.child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val userid = p0.child("uid").getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d(TAG, "User: " + userid)
        }
    })
}
```

The function, however, returns null. I am not being able to understand why

Comment: Is your log statement printing?

Comment: Yes it is printing User: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should traverse the database from the parent node to the value that you want.

In your code you need to change the following:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
```

Into this:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users");
```

Comment: It says since I have less than 15 reputation I cannot vote. I am new to stackoverflow as well

Comment: You can mark as correct even if you have 0 reputation. You have to mark it as accepted, not upvote it.